# XPath for Selecting Dynamic date in Date Picker Calendar

Tags: xpath, datepicker, calendar, html-email, webmail

I need a custom xpath to select a dynamic date from date picker in webmail.
My earlier xpath was - //div[contains(@class, 'ms-FocusZone')]//tr/td[contains(@class, 'datesRight')]/button[@aria-label='$strFullMonthName$']
where $strFullMonthName$ is date Eg. 15, June, 2023.

Now the webmail has changed and I am unable to make the new xpath dynamic.
New absolute xpath is -

> //div[@id='fluent-default-layer-host']/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[5]/td[5]/button[1]

Inner HTML -

> span aria-hidden="true">15</span

""  [I selected date as 15 June for this example]
Outer HTML -

> button class="dayButton-427" aria-label="15, June, 2023"
> type="button" tabindex="-1" data-is-focusable="false">15</button

I would like to have an xpath which I used to have earlier so that I can push any dynamic date of the selected month and the xpath can fill that accordingly.[Page Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qdal.png)

Comment: what about just `//button[@aria-label='15, June, 2023']` ?

Comment: Nope.. doesnt work for other dates! Already tried!

Comment: What do you mean "for other dates"?

Comment: I think this could work `//div/table/tbody/tr/td/button[.//span[number(text())]]`